# Как посчитать количество комбинаций карт?

Tags: python, алгоритм, комбинаторика

> Из хорошо перетасованной малой колоды карт (от семерок до тузов, 4 масти, всего 32 карты) вам выдают 6 карт подряд. Какое количество комбинаций выданные карты в сумме дают 50 очков? Считайте, что валет – это 11 очков, дама – 12 очков, король – 13 очков, туз – 14 очков. Число очков для остальных карт совпадает с их номиналом.
> Как это можно реализовать на python с помощью модуля itertools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю правильно ли посчитал, но так:

```
from itertools import combinations

cards = list(range(7, 15)) * 4
print(len(list(filter(lambda x: sum(x) == 50, combinations(cards, 6)))))
# 2698
```

И ещё один, совсем функциональный вариант в качестве развлечения - без лямбды и равно, но с двумя лишними библиотеками. Результат тот же.

```
from itertools import combinations
from operator import eq
from functools import partial

cards = list(range(7, 15)) * 4
print(sum(map(partial(eq, 50), map(sum, combinations(cards, 6)))))
# 2698
```

Если нужно могу пояснить код, но, кажется, он читается довольно прозрачно.